# Populating label from user input on another form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have populated a label in VB.Net using what has been input in a text box on another form however, when i then try and use the content of that label in a piece of code, it shows that there is nothing in the label?

Comment: the code is Me.lblStudentID.Text = frmLogin.txtUserID.Text

Comment: This code shows the correct value, however when i try and use the value of that label it creates an error. When troubleshooting with a msg box it shows there is nothing in the label

Comment: What do you mean by "it creates an error"?

Comment: you should check if frmLogin is open before you copy the text.

Comment: frmLogin is hidden, then frmStudentMenu is shown (the form where lblStudentID is). When frmStudentMenu is loaded the code above is run to fill the label. So the login form is still 'open' it's just hidden. - When i say "it creates and error", i mean that there is an error when i run the code

Comment: For some reason there is no content in the label. On the form it shows up with the correct information however when i try and take the content of the label in another form it shows there is nothing in that label

Comment: Use the @ symbol when you are answering to someone. Did you find the problem?

Comment: Sorry @valter I'm new to stack overflow. Sorted the issue but now have a new issue!

Comment: What is the new problem?